# How Many Self-Avoiding Walks are there in a 3x8 Grid of Nodes where all nodes must be traversed.

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, hamiltonian-path

You must start from the bottom left corner of the grid and end at the top right corner. From my research, most solutions focus on all possible self-avoiding walks but not the specific case where every single node is passed through. I understand simpler cases where the movement is restricted to right and up moves but not the general case where you can move down and left. I am trying to look for an invariant in the question and I think that there must always be 23 moves but that doesn't really get me anywhere. Any hints to do this question? The solution seems to be 64.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you found results on smaller grids?

Comment: i've tried taking cases but it just seems way too complicated. i haven't found a systematic way of counting cases, ik for a 2x2 grid it would be 2 cases, 3x3 grid would also be two cases but then for non-square grids it becomes a lot more challenging

Comment: There's a formula here (but not a derivation): https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Self-AvoidingWalk.html

Answer (score 1):

You will find that from experimentation for small $n$ that for a grid with $3$ rows  and $n$ columns with $n>1$,

- the number of acceptable routes from bottom left to *top* right is $t(n)=2^{n-2}$
- the number of acceptable routes from bottom left to *bottom right* $b(n) =2^{n-2}$ too.

In discovering this, you should be able to see that $t(n)=1+\sum\limits_{i=2}^{n-1} b(i)$ and $b(n)=1+\sum\limits_{i=2}^{n-1} t(i)$, justified with diagrams like this

[image]

and so the proof of the result can use strong induction.

Comment: For a more general point of view (that you don't need for your exercise), see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1386057/305862)

Comment: @JeanMarie $3$ is a special case (so too are $1$ and $2$ in different ways) and I suspect it becomes much harder with $4$